# Simple for statement won't proceed through loop?

Tags: java, for-loop

I have been trying to fix my for statement for some time now and I now have to bother you lot!

I am reading a .txt file, storing its data into an array called `temp`. I am adding a new string to this array and then saving it back to the .txt file. Simple...I know!

My code is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // Defining
    String token = "";

    // Tokensize user input.
    Scanner action = new Scanner(System.in);
    String tokenized = action.nextLine();
    String[] tokenizes = tokenized.split("\\s");

    // Read the 'greetings' part of the first sentence.

    // Open 'greetings.txt' and save data to an array.
    Scanner file1 = new Scanner(new File("greetings.txt"));
    List<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (file1.hasNext()) {
      token = file1.next();
      temp.add(token);
    }
    temp.add(tokenized);
    file1.close();

    System.out.println(temp);
    System.out.println(temp.get(1));
    System.out.println(temp.get(2));

    int arraylength = temp.size();

    System.out.println(arraylength);

    // Write the users greetings into the .txt.
    // Overwrite old greetings array data.
    PrintWriter writing = new PrintWriter("greetings.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < arraylength; i++) {
    writing.println(temp.get(i));
    writing.write("\n");
    writing.close();
    }
    }
}
```

The issue is, the for loop only saves `temp(0)` to the `greetings.txt` file. It's not cycling through `i` to `arraylength`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `writing.close();` out of the for loop. In the code you provided you close the print writer in the first iteration (you call `writer.close()` in each iteration, in fact). That is, change

```
for (int i = 0; i < arraylength; i++) {
    writing.println(temp.get(i));
    writing.write("\n");
    writing.close();
}
```

into

```
for (int i = 0; i < arraylength; i++) {
    writing.println(temp.get(i));
    writing.write("\n");
}
writing.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your closing writing in your for loop. Moving writing.close () after your for loop should do the trick.